# Output single post custom taxonomy child terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to output links to custom taxonomy assigned to a single post on a single post page. I've tried other thing but get errors. This is the closest I can get. It just needs to find the terms for the current post instead of outputting all terms of a taxonomy.

```
<?php
    $term_id = 6;
    $taxonomy_name = 'categories';
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
        foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
        echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a> ';
    }
    ?>
```

@Howdy_McGee I tried the following code, where 'adoption-status' is a term for the custom taxonomy 'categories'. I'm looking for children of 'adoption-status'. It doesn't output anything. No errors either.

```
<?php get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'adoption-status' ); ?>
```

The following code almost works but displays all 'categories' of the current post, not just those of the term (or sub-category) 'adoption-status'

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'categories', '', '', '' );?>
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for is get_the_terms(): http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms

Comment: Yeah, I tried that already but doesn't work.

Comment: @TroyTempleman what was the output that didn't make it work? Could you post your implementation?

Comment: Could you possibly edit your question with the implementation you tried? Michelle is right, `get_the_terms` is usually the best bet for what you need.

Comment: @TroyTempleman looking at the [`get_the_terms()` Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) it says that you need to pass in a taxonomy and your original code has the taxonomy as `categories` so instead of `adoption-status` maybe try `categories` instead. Also, if you're trying to get the built-in **Post** Categories, then the taxonomy is actually called `category`.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee that doesn't work either (no errors). Even if it did, it would likely output all categories as get_the_term_list example did.

Comment: @TroyTempleman Please read the [linked Codex on how `get_the_terms()` works](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms). It doesn't list anything it returns an array of objects.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee OK I tried the basic example there, substituting 'on-draught' with 'categories' but it lists all terms for that post. The problem is getting only the child terms of the "sub-category" of 'adoption-status'.

Comment: I see let me look it over once more, it was a little confusing when you stated "It just needs to find the terms for the current post instead of outputting all terms of a taxonomy."

Comment: @Howdy_McGee OK. To clarify, this is for a single post page. There are categories for each post (a custom taxonomy, not built in post categories). One of the categories is "Adoption Status", which has a few "sub-categories". I want to display which one of these sub-categories is selected for each post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21269/discussion-between-howdy-mcgee-and-troy-templeman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand your question. You are looking for all terms connected to a single post, but only terms that are children to the `adoption-status` term

To get all the terms from a specific post, you can make use of [`wp_get_post_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms). This will return all the terms of a specific taxonomy connected to the post.

You will also need to make use of [`get_term_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) to get all the child terms from your `adoption-status` term

Once you have all that, it is simply to compare the two, and only returning the terms that are associated with the post and is a child term to your given term.

You can try something like the following (*NOTE: Change the term ids and taxonomy names accordingly*)

```
$child_terms = get_term_children(21, 'category');
$all_terms   = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category');

foreach ( $all_terms as $term ) {

    if( !in_array($term->term_id, $child_terms ) ) 
        continue;

    echo $term->name;

}
```

Comment: I tried changing the term id and taxonomy name to $child_terms = get_term_children(6, 'categories'); but get an error.

Comment: What error. You should change taxonomy in `wp_get_post_terms` as well. Most probably because the taxonomy don't exist

Comment: Pieter, I changed that too 'categories' also but get the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF"?

Comment: My bad, I had an extra if statement left in there by mistake. I take it out and get nothing, and no error.

Comment: Recheck your code and ID's. On my installation, I have a child term and a grandchild term which belongs to term `21`. With this code, only the child term and grandchild term are retrieved

Comment: Yeah, I've double checked. It seems like it should work but maybe there's another external issue, which might explain why I haven't had much luck with anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Where exacrly are you using this, are you using any custom queries that might influence the result. My code definitely works on my own theme and the bundled themes.

Comment: I believe you because I just got it working on the default theme. Must be something with my theme that I'm going to have to investigate. Thanks again Pieter!

Comment: My pleasure. Just a tip, investigate any filter, and all custom queries on your page. And if you are maybe using query_posts, then that is causing your issues. I really do feel that something is breaking your main query. Good luck. :-)